# Laravel echo session value or default

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a redirect from my controller:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('auto', time());
```

And in my blade template:

```
<input type="hidden" name="auto" value="{{ session('auto') or 'abcd' }}">
```

However, when I get redirected back to the page, my input has the value `1` instead. No matter what value I redirect it, it's echoing `1`, which stands for `true` I suppose.

So I'm doing it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="auto" value="<?php echo session('auto') ? session('auto') : 'abcd'; ?>">
```

How can I get the value of `session('auto`)` the Laravel way?

Comment: `session('auto','abcd')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `has()` method to check if session has `auto` key:

```
value="{{ session->has('auto') ? session('auto') : 'abcd' }}"
```

Or use [default value](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#using-the-session):

```
value="{{ session()->get('auto', 'abcd') }}"
```

Or like @apokryfos has shown:

```
value="{{ session('auto', 'abcd') }}"
```